# Simple text glob PathMatcher not working in Java

Tags: java, glob

I'm not getting Java's glob `PathMatcher`. I have a path with a filename `example.txt`. I have a Glob to match `*.txt`. But it doesn't seem to match.

Here's my basic JUnit5 unit test with Hamcrest:

```java
@Test
void testGlob(@TempDir final Path tempDir) throws IOException {
  Path directory = createDirectory(tempDir.resolve("foobar"));
  Path exampleTxtFile = writeString(directory.resolve("example.txt"), "example");
  PathMatcher pathMatcher = directory.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:*.txt");
  assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(exampleTxtFile), is(true));
}
```

The test fails. Why?

It seems to work if I use a glob of `**.txt`. But that's not the way globs usually work in real life. If I have a relative glob such as `*.txt`, it's usually understood that I just want to match it against any filename. Isn't that how it usually works? If I wanted to match the whole path, I would specify the whole path, such as `/foo/bar/foobar/*.txt`.

Is this just an idiosyncrasy of the Java glob implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the matcher is trying to match `/foo/bar/foobar/example.txt` with the `/` that represents a directory hierarchy but `"glob:*.txt"` matches any file name with `.txt` extension. When you use `"glob:**.txt"` it match any string so the sub-path too. If you change the code like this way it will work

```
@Test
void testGlob(@TempDir final Path tempDir) throws IOException {
  Path directory = createDirectory(tempDir.resolve("foobar"));
  Path exampleTxtFile = writeString(directory.resolve("example.txt"), "example");
  PathMatcher pathMatcher = directory.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:*.txt");
  assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(exampleTxtFile.getFileName()), is(true));
}
```